# How can I share the internet connection between an android phone and a macbook?

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, tethering, android

I try to create a portable Wi-Fi hotspot with my android Sony Xperia P (android 4.2.3) as it works with Windows flawlessly. With the macbook, I connect with the newly created Wi-Fi hotspot. The mac seems to connect (it gets an IP from the phone), but I can't navigate. Nothing happens. It is stuck.

Any idea?

The mac is a Macbook pro retina 13, with updated Mountain Lion.

Comment: can you ping a website from the terminal ?

Comment: Nope. I get a timeout after a while

Comment: Are you using an password for WiFi ?